# How to unit test Hangfire implementation using Hangfire.MemoryStorage

Tags: c#, unit-testing, asp.net-core, moq, hangfire

To clarify what I'm trying to do, I have a method that creates/updates an item in my DB. When Testing as usual by asserting that the item is in the in-memory database always comes back as null. After reading the docs, it appears I need to be determining whether or not the correct job has been added to the Hangfire queue.

I've been going over the [documentation](http://docs.hangfire.io/en/latest/background-methods/writing-unit-tests.html) for unit testing a Hangfire implementation but can't seem to find a way to test against in-memory storage.

In the example, a mock is created and then passed into the constructor of the controller. However, I've been modeling my solution after [this example](https://github.com/HangfireIO/Hangfire/pull/604) where jobs are queued in the Configure method of the Startup class. This means I have no controller and I'm not passing anything into my methods that are queuing up my jobs.

So how should I be going about testing this?

Here's one of the methods I'm trying to test:

```
public async Task SyncDeletedAccounts()
    {
        try
        {
            int pastMinutes = 90;
            var startDate = DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(0 - pastMinutes);
            var client = await this._forceDotComService.GetForceClient();

            var deletedIds = await this._forceDotComService.GetDeletedIds<sf.Account>(client, startDate);
            if (!deletedIds.Any())
            {
                this._logger.LogInformation("No deleted accounts");
                return;
            }

            foreach (var deletedId in deletedIds)
            {
                BackgroundJob.Enqueue<InterconnectorServiceHelper<sf.Account, ic.Account>>(i =>
                    i.MarkDeleted(deletedId));
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            this._logger.LogError(e, "AccountService.SyncDeletedAccounts");
            throw;
        }
    }
```

Comment: show us the parts code which you want to unit test

Comment: @Yogi - I updated my question